# When using transform.Translate in Unity3D outside of an update loop, how can I perform collision detection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

So I'm writing a small multiplayer game. For this, I'm using basic cube colliders for the players. At the moment, set to isKinematic.

Each player is moved from the main loop, using an offset timer to account for lag/latency. This works fine. However, with this method, collisions are a problem. 
I do NOT want to use Force if I can avoid it - a previous attempt proved that to be a big issue. transform.Translate() works best or so it seems, but it does not account for anything hitting meshes. isKinematic disables OnCollisionEnter. I would love to use rigidbody.velocity, but it needs to account for rotation, not four-way movement.

This is my tick code at the moment:

```
public void FixedStep(double T)
{
    if (Last == 0.0) Last = T;

    double Offset = System.Math.Min(T - Last, 5000);

    for (double X = 0.0; X < Offset; X++)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Speed * -mInput.y * Time.deltaTime);
        //mRigidBody.velocity = (Vector3.forward * Speed * mInput.y);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * TurnSpeed * mInput.x * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    Last = T;
}
```

I remember there used to be tutorials that combined forward movement and rotation for rigidbody.velocity, but for the life of me, I can't find them. Does anyone have advice on collisions with this method?

Comment: I have all sorts of questions about your code and your approach. What's wrong with FixedUpdate()? Why can't you use transform.forward to adjust rigidbody.velocity? You can set rigidbody.velocity even if isKinematic is off. If you're dead set on not using the physics engine you could just raycast.

Comment: I am using FixedUpdate - it's the main loop in the game controller. The code is designed so that all players run off a main FixedUpdate loop and are updated using a Time tick, to account for lag/latency - that's the double in FixedStep. Nothing is wrong with rigidbody.velocity, but nearly all modern examples I have seen build out for four-way movement.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I feel stupid. It's been long enough since I've done a ...somewhat conventional game that I completely forgot the proper method of using rigidbody.velocity.

mRigidBody.velocity = transform.forward * Speed * -mInput.y;